# Convert raster_stats list output to array / csv file

Tags: python, raster, zonal-statistics, list

I usually program in R, but recently I have started to use python for most of my spatial programming. My python skills are still limited, and please excuse the simplicity of the question. I am struggling to convert a list, which is an output of a spatial function, into an array / csv file. In particular, I struggle how to disaggregate the list output that i receive from the spatial function.

Here is the spatial function I have used:

```
from rasterstats import raster_stats
import time

os.chdir("C:/Users/Documents/veg_dt/data")

start = time.time()
stats_n_w = raster_stats("counties.shp", "veg_ndv.tif",stats=['count'], categorical=True)
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

The function raster_stats counts the occurrence of a categorical variable in a set of polygons. The output of the function is a list, and this is the actual output:

```
{0: 31728, 1: 35, 2: 31, 3: 30, 4: 29, 5: 40, 6: 44, 7: 82, 8: 85, 9: 142, 10: 20, 11: 58, 12: 76, 'count': 32400, '__fid__': 39989}
{0: 32204, 1: 6, 2: 13, 3: 5, 4: 15, 5: 27, 6: 33, 7: 5, 8: 28, 9: 28, 11: 3, 12: 33, 'count': 32400, '__fid__': 39990}
{0: 31983, 1: 38, 2: 11, 3: 21, 4: 42, 5: 17, 6: 19, 7: 52, 8: 66, 9: 34, 10: 9, 11: 87, 12: 21, 'count': 32400, '__fid__': 39991}
{0: 32400, 'count': 32400, '__fid__': 39992}
```

Every element of the list counts the categorical variable in a given polygon. The first row shows 31,728 zeros, 35 ones, 31 twos, 30 threes, 29 fours, 40 fives, etc in polygon 39989. The second element has 32,204 zeros, six ones, etc in polygon 39990. I would like to convert the list into a data frame / array / eventually csv file that states the fid (id of the polygon cells) in the first column, then lists the occurrences of zero in the second column, lists the occurrences of ones in the third column, etc. I want to have every element of the list on one row.

Also, to complicate things further, the list is around 60,000 elements and I will do the same operation approximately 50 times for different sets of polygon and tiff images.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you seen the rasterstats.stats_to_csv example in [this tutorial](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2013/09/24/python-raster-stats)?

Comment: @Luke excellent i had not seen that -- will try out thanks!!!!! I oversaw it when I looked at the document